# Playing notification audio files outside of notifications in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I'm looking for a way to play the audio files which are used for `LocalNotificaiton`s (notification_sound_xyz.mp3) when clicking a button for example.

I want to provide to the user the possibility to set the notification's sound as he prefer by previewing the sounds. I know that the notification audio files are moved to different locations depending on the OS. Therefore I'm wondering whether we can access those by CN.openFileInputStream or sth alike. Or do I have to write native code?

Regardless of the approach to access these files, as a result I want to put the references to those files in a `MediaManager.createMedia`call from CN1 in order to play the previews.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting two copies of the files one in the project one which you can play and one for the native playback as these things could be fragile otherwise.

Comment: that's something I wanted to avoid but I suppose there's no better solution then